# Android assets no such file or directory

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions, inputstream, assets

In my android project I have created an assets folder in which I have added some json files and I want to read them with a stringBuffer. The assets folder is listed inside src/main. So far I have added the following code:

```
   String[] files = assetManager.list("");
   ArrayList<String> it = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(files));
```

And so far I am getting the names of the files successfully inside my ArrayList. Then I am trying this:

```
InputStream input = assetManager.open("filename.json");
```

But I get the following error:

> Failed to open file
>
> '/data/data/package/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/filename.json':
> No such file or directory

I also have included the follwing permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Any idea what might be the problem here?

Comment: It is impossible that you get that error with the code you posted.

Comment: You also dont need those permissions to read from assets resource.

Comment: @blackapps That's what I figured but this is what I get. Regarding the permissions I added them just in case it was the problem. Thank you for your response though.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, the app crash randomly with the same error log

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue on my Android project many times. Try uninstalling the app on your emulator and rebuild your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear storage in device and then rebuild app, that help my same issue.